# Can a hyphen be used instead of & in URL Parameters

Tags: url, parameters

I want to use a hyphen instead of an & in a URL parameter

Typically my URL is www.mysite.com?id=233&company-name

[ where id=233 is a news story ]

But I would like to format the URL Parameter with a hyphen instead of an &

www.mysite.com?id=233-company-name

Comment: How would you distinguish between parameter separators and interned hyphens? For example, in the example URL you provided, you want the first hyphen to be interpreted as a separator but the second is part of your parameter name.  Generally speaking if you have access to backend source code / config, you can do what you're trying to do but it rarely is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Nidal. That's a good point. Have you seen it actually written anywhere ?   Like definition of ? and & in URL parameters. I am sure it must be defined in one of the languages.

Comment: Also, I just realised that, in this case I am not actually including an argument. I am actually just appending some information about the page. [ ie a company name ]

Comment: It is a standard that has been used on the web as far as i can remember. As for "where" it is written: that depends on the programming language your server/backend is written in. For example, for django servers, it's probably written in the code for the views in the main library. You'll likely have to override the core django library to make it work the way you want it to.